# Java source code deobfuscator?

Tags: obfuscation, java, deobfuscation

Does anyone know of any source code deobfuscator in java?
I'm currently writing an obfuscator for java source code and I want to test how well I have made it with an deobfuscator.

Comment: There's lots. Did you even try searching?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+deobfuscation

Comment: Have you tried [JMD](https://github.com/contra/JMD) ?